# How to Sort Seaborn barplot in ascending or descending order

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-visualization

The EXCEL file has the information about 7000 Apple App store, here is how it looks

[image]

This is my code ->

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
apple_store_data = pd.read_excel(r'apple_store.xlsx')
sns.barplot(data=apple_store_data,y='PrimaryGenre',x='AvgRating',color='g')
plt.show()
```

and it gives output like this ->

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To order the bars alphabetically, you could make the column [categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) with `ordered=True`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Genre': np.random.choice(['helium', 'neon', 'argon', 'krypton', 'xenon', 'radon', 'oganesson'], 50),
                   'Rating': np.random.randint(1, 11, 50)})
df['Genre'] = pd.Categorical(df['Genre'], ordered=True)
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, y='Genre', x='Rating', palette='husl')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', length=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

To order the bars in descending order, you could use the following code. In that case the column doesn't need to be made categorical.

```py
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, y='Genre', x='Rating', palette='plasma',
                 order=df.groupby('Genre')['Rating'].agg('mean').sort_values(ascending=False).index)
```

[image: seaborn sorted bar plot]

PS: To only show e.g. the top 5, use `... .index[:5]`:

```py
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, y='Genre', x='Rating', palette='plasma',
                 order=df.groupby('Genre')['Rating'].agg('mean').sort_values(ascending=False).index[:5])
```